# Remove non-ascii character in string

Tags: javascript, non-ascii-characters

```
var str="INFO] :谷���新道, ひば���ヶ丘２丁���, ひばりヶ���, 東久留米市 (Higashikurume)";
```

and i need to remove all non-ascii character from string,

means str only contain "INFO] (Higashikurume)";

Answer (score 324):

ASCII is in range of 0 to 127, so:

```
str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
```

Comment: @AlexanderMills Search for an ascii table - you can see that only characters that has value from zero to 127 are valid. (0x7F is 127 in hex). This code matches all characters that are not in the ascii range and removes them.

Comment: thanks for sharing. Would you mind to explain how  \x7F  works? Thanks again.

Comment: @eyyo IIt represents the last character ascii character. I can't give you a full explanation in a comment like this. It's called hexadecimal escape sequence, if you search for it, you will surely find tons of information about it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could edit your answer with additional info of how this works, right now it's not really helping me understand

Answer (score 49):

It can also be done with a positive assertion of removal, like this:

```
textContent = textContent.replace(/[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu,"");
```

This uses unicode.  In Javascript, when expressing unicode for a regular expression, the characters are specified with the escape sequence `\u{xxxx}` but also the flag `'u'` must present; note the regex has flags `'gu'`.

I called this a "positive assertion of removal" in the sense that a "positive" assertion expresses which characters to remove, while a "negative" assertion expresses which letters to not remove.  In many contexts, the negative assertion, as stated in the prior answers, might be more suggestive to the reader.  The circumflex "`^`" says "not" and the range `\x00-\x7F` says "ascii," so the two together say "not ascii."

```
textContent = textContent.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g,"");
```

That's a great solution for English language speakers who only care about the English language, and its also a fine answer for the original question.  But in a more general context, one cannot always accept the cultural bias of assuming "all non-ascii is bad."  For contexts where non-ascii is used, but occasionally needs to be stripped out, the positive assertion of Unicode is a better fit.

A good indication that zero-width, non printing characters are embedded in a string is when the string's "length" property is positive (nonzero), but looks like (i.e. prints as) an empty string.  For example, I had this showing up in the Chrome debugger, for a variable named "textContent":

```
> textContent
""
> textContent.length
7
```

This prompted me to want to see what was in that string.

```
> encodeURI(textContent)
"%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B"
```

This sequence of bytes seems to be in the family of some Unicode characters that get inserted by word processors into documents, and then find their way into data fields.  Most commonly, these symbols occur at the end of a document.  The zero-width-space `"%E2%80%8B"` might be inserted by CK-Editor (CKEditor).

```
encodeURI()  UTF-8     Unicode  html     Meaning
-----------  --------  -------  -------  -------------------
"%E2%80%8B"  EC 80 8B  U 200B   &#8203;  zero-width-space
"%E2%80%8E"  EC 80 8E  U 200E   &#8206;  left-to-right-mark
"%E2%80%8F"  EC 80 8F  U 200F   &#8207;  right-to-left-mark
```

Some references on those:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Note that although the encoding of the embedded character is UTF-8, the encoding  in the regular expression is not.  Although the character is embedded in the string as three bytes (in my case) of UTF-8, the instructions in the regular expression must use the two-byte Unicode.  In fact, UTF-8 can be up to four bytes long; it is less compact than Unicode because it uses the high bit (or bits) to escape the standard ascii encoding.  That's explained here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: `textContent = textContent.replace(/[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu,"");` doesn't work in IE (at least IE 11). It fails with error: **SCRIPT5021**: _Invalid range in character set_

Answer (score 24):

You can use the following regex to replace non-ASCII characters

```
str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '')
```

However, note that spaces, colons and commas are all valid ASCII, so the result will be

```
> str
"INFO] :, , ,  (Higashikurume)"
```

Comment: I am not great with regex but know the .replace() method takes the thing that you want to replace and replaces the 2nd parameter like .replace('replace this text', 'with this text'). So what part of that says do the opposite and leave the ascii characters and remove the others. Thanks.

Comment: @NicoM Characters in `[]` mean any character but in `[^]` mean the opposite - match any character not in the brackets.

Answer (score 19):

None of these answers properly handle tabs, newlines, carriage returns, and some don't handle extended ASCII and unicode.
This will KEEP tabs & newlines, but remove control characters and anything out of the ASCII set. Click "Run this code snippet" button to test. There is some new javascript coming down the pipe so in the future (2020+?) you may have to do `\u{FFFFF}` but not yet

```js
console.log("line 1\nline2 \n\ttabbed\nF̸̡̢͓̳̜̪̟̳̠̻̖͐̂̍̅̔̂͋͂͐l̸̢̹̣̤̙͚̱͓̖̹̻̣͇͗͂̃̈͝a̸̢̡̬͕͕̰̖͍̮̪̬̍̏̎̕͘ͅv̸̢̛̠̟̄̿i̵̮͌̑ǫ̶̖͓͎̝͈̰̹̫͚͓̠̜̓̈́̇̆̑͜ͅ".replace(/[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\uFFFF]/g, ''))
```

Comment: it is a good regex, but it also removes accents and emojis. I'm not sure how improve this regex to cover these cases.

Comment: For anyone looking for a possible solution to removing Angular window.atob and DOMSanitizer.bypassSecurity... invalid characters (be it %80, \uFFFF or unexplained whitespaces) when converting to base64, this is a working solution

Answer (score 17):

To use ASCII with accents:

```
var str = str.replace(/[^\x00-\xFF]/g, "");
```

Comment: Brilliant! Handles ascii values above 127 that other answers throw away.

Comment: How about alt text with accents...like https://altcodeunicode.com/alt-codes-letter-e-with-accents/?

Answer (score 2):

```
str = str.replace(/[\u{0080}-\u{10FFFF}]/gu,"");
```