# Parse JSON throws error while using Special characters

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have parsed the below string but it s not parsed because of the character ('****'),

```
JSON.parse("{\"data\":\"value \"}")
```

It throws error,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 15

How can i get rid of this.

*Note: In my case i need to skip all the special characters, which came dynamically. So i need to generic solution. Can i make it?*

[image]

Comment: can you pass it not escaped? are you reading it from DB?

Comment: I'm reading the _excel file (Which may or may not contains these type of special characters)_ from server side and return the json string to client side, then i'll convert the json string into object.

Comment: You could do a replace of any non utf 8 character before you do the parse. Try the regex from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856346.  JSON.parse("{\"data\":\"value \"}".replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, ""))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some special characters are coming from excel file. Try this,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = function () {
            var str ='{\"data\":\"value \ \"}'.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
               .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
               .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
               .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
               .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
               .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
               .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
               .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
            var d = JSON.parse(str);
            alert(d.data);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The Special character not showing in this post for some reason, so i have attached image of it.. Please refer that image.