# How to replace all chinese character from a string?

Tags: javascript, replace

I tried the code below

```
str = 'Arc's 弧'
str.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi,'');
```

The result show

```
Arc039s
```

Expected result

```
Arc's
```

What's wrong with the code, and is that the right way for removing chinese character including punctuation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure the actual string wasn’t `"Arc&#039;s 弧"`? Is your input HTML? And why do you want to remove those characters?

Comment: @Ryan yes, i get it from database and want to share some text via whatsapp, if contain chinese character whatsapp unable to send the text properly.

Comment: Have try to escape Chinese character instead of remove it?

Comment: escaping should work, I also faced the same problem with another unicode based language. escaping worked for me

Comment: and if you really want to remove non-ascii characters the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856197/remove-non-ascii-character-in-string may help you

Comment: how escape() work? Is it same like replace()? I just want to send text via whatsapp by trim all chinese character but replace() method seem not working.

Answer (score 3):

Check this

```
var  str = "Arc's 弧"
alert (str);
// by your regex
alert (str.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi,''));
// by new regex which removes non-ascii characters
alert(str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, ""));
```

`str.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi,'')` will remove chinese character but it will also remove `'` so your new string will will be `Arcs` but by `str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "")` regex it will remove non-ascii characters and new string will be `Arc's`.

http://jsfiddle.net/yjcL5/104/

Comment: It is not working in my case, i only able to display Arc and the characters left behind will not able to be displayed if i share text to whatsapp.

Comment: @Zidance To understand better, create a fiddle with exact same code that you are using

Comment: I can't create a jsfiddle because it is caused when display the data from my database. If i am creating a sample data with apostrophe, i don't see any problem.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin and the collation is latin1_swedish_ci. Is this related?

Comment: I can't tell what is happening by actually looking it but still on a note what you are saying just make sure value retrieved from DB is UTF8/unicode, mention charset=utf8 for mysql connection string. and yes DB collation also plays important role. I suggest to try with `utf_unicode_ci`