# Comparing 2 seemingly equal strings returns false because one ends with char code 8291. How can I sanitize the string?

Tags: javascript, string, coffeescript, char, comparison

I'm trying to compare the string "Anyone" to an object value that is also supposed to be "Anyone" and looks equal when logging to the console.

I'm checking the 2 strings using:

```
for char, index in text
    console.log "char " + index + ": " + text.charCodeAt(index)
```

One string returns one extra character with the code 8291. What character is this and how can I remove it? 
.trim() and using a regex whitespace remover doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856197/remove-non-ascii-character-in-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using `str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");`.
Which removes all non-ascii characters.